# Dynamically add input to list item (iOS5 reminder-like)

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I add an item to a List using the same method of iOS5 Reminder? I'd like the "New" button to add an input to the last, empty item of the list, focus on it and let the user add the new item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still need some improvement, but it works.

[Demo](http://titouanvanbelle.fr/GitHub/Sencha/Ext.ux.Reminder/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/Sencha/tree/master/Ext.ux.Reminder)

Hope this helps