# sencha touch list with add item capability

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2, addition

I have a list (Ext.dataview.List) and i want to add an textbox at the end of the list in order to add an item to that list. Is there any built-in solution to my problem?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in solution but I did something like this once.

[Take a look at my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892792/dynamically-add-input-to-list-item-ios5-reminder-like)

Hope this helped